# How do i remove undesired linebreaks in text only?

Tags: pycharm, yaml, line-breaks

How do i remove undesired linebreaks in text only (yml file, Pycharm ide)?

```
utter_ask_family10:
- text: "I'm helping my parents, but don't let Dad hear me.)
But it is very difficult. I say I have money - listen to me, please, I bought you a Honda car,
 you're my dad, you have an anniversary, I want to give you... It didn't work out."
- text: "Helping my parents is very difficult, they don't take money from me, but through gifts. Daddy in general - we fight with him."
```

Desired output:

```
utter_ask_family10:
- text: "I'm helping my parents, but don't let Dad hear me.) But it is very difficult. I say I have money - listen to me, please, I bought you a Honda car, you're my dad, you have an anniversary, I want to give you... It didn't work out."
- text: "Helping my parents is very difficult, they don't take money from me, but through gifts. Daddy in general - we fight with him."
```

As you can see this removes \n but also add a "whitespace" before every text part (like before "But")

Think of regex but it simply removes \n\n

Comment: You write *desired output* but then argue as if it was the actual output. If so, what did you do to get this actual output? Also, your input is not valid YAML, e.g. `But` must be more indented than its key `text:`, same for `you're`.

Comment: I have done it by hand. Yes, it is not valid yaml, thats why i am asking how to convert it to valid

Comment: If your input is not valid YAML, you need to formally define its structure before you can start thinking about how to transform it to valid YAML. Is it something like „YAML but rules for indentation of double quoted scalars are ignored and all line breaks in double quoted scalars are not part of the scalar content“?